# Incorrect display using IBO with glDrawElements and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3

I've written a simple OpenGL program to draw a simple uv-mapped cube (created on Blender). But the output is not correct.

[image]

Here's the OBJ file content:

```
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.626059 0.265705
vt 0.626059 0.487398
vt 0.404365 0.487398
vt 0.626060 0.930786
vt 0.404365 0.930786
vt 0.404365 0.709091
vt 0.847752 0.487397
vt 0.847753 0.709091
vt 0.626059 0.709091
vt 0.182672 0.487397
vt 0.626059 0.044011
vt 0.404366 0.265704
vt 0.182671 0.709091
vt 0.404366 0.044011
usemtl BoxMtl
s off
f 1/1 2/2 3/3
f 5/4 8/5 7/6
f 1/7 5/8 6/9
f 2/2 6/9 3/3
f 3/3 7/6 4/10
f 5/11 1/1 4/12
f 4/12 1/1 3/3
f 6/9 5/4 7/6
f 2/2 1/7 6/9
f 6/9 7/6 3/3
f 7/6 8/13 4/10
f 8/14 5/11 4/12
```

So here's the vertex position array :

```
static GLfloat position[24] =
{
    1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,
    1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000,
    -1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000,
    -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,
    1.000000, 1.000000, -0.999999,
    0.999999, 1.000000, 1.000001,
    -1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000,
    -1.000000, 1.000000, -1.000000
};
```

The vertex texture coordinates array :

```
static GLfloat texture[28] = {
    0.626059, 0.265705,
    0.626059, 0.487398,
    0.404365, 0.487398,
    0.626060, 0.930786,
    0.404365, 0.930786,
    0.404365, 0.709091,
    0.847752, 0.487397,
    0.847753, 0.709091,
    0.626059, 0.709091,
    0.182672, 0.487397,
    0.626059, 0.044011,
    0.404366, 0.265704,
    0.182671, 0.709091,
    0.404366, 0.044011
};
```

And here's a proposition for the index buffer:

```
static GLuint indices[72] = {
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
    4, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5,
    0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
    1, 5, 2, 1, 8, 2,
    2, 6, 3, 2, 5, 9,
    4, 0, 3, 10, 0, 11,
    3, 0, 2, 11, 0, 2,
    5, 4, 6, 8, 3, 5,
    1, 0, 5, 1, 6, 8,
    5, 6, 2, 8, 5, 2,
    6, 7, 3, 5, 12, 9,
    7, 4, 3, 7, 10, 11
};
```

the syntax is the following (but I'm not sure it's the correct one):

```
v1, v2, v3, vt1, vt2, vt3,
v4, v5, v6, vt4, vt5, vt6,
etc.
```

Now here's the code to initialize VBOs and the IBO :

```
GLuint vertex_vboId;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_vboId);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(GLfloat), position, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

GLuint texture_vboId;
glGenBuffers(1, &texture_vboId);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 28 * sizeof(GLfloat), texture, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

GLuint indexId;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexId);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexId);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36 * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And finally the code in the main loop :

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(offset) ((char*)NULL + (offset))

[..]

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_vboId);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_vboId);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexId);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

I'm lost but I'm almost sure the problem comes from the disposition of the index array but I can't find the solution. Maybe I have to call glDrawElements for each VBO but I'd like to have a simple one. Belongs to you, does the syntax if the index buffer is correct ? Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: I believe OpenGL & Blender use different coordinate systems (right vs. left). have you account for this in your code?

Comment: The only adverse affect that would have is on polygon winding (e.g. wrong face is culled).

Comment: If those indices are supposed to create a ***triangle list***, then this strikes me as very odd: `0, 1, 2,  0, 1, 2,` That is the same triangle twice.

Comment: Yes Freedy, I've completely forgotten this point. In fact, the problem comes from the texture coordinates. To translate them from Blender to OpenGL coordinates system I have to apply the following equation : vt(y -> OpenGL) = 1 - vt (y -> Blender). For the x axis this is the same. I will try this when I'll be back home and I'll tell you the final solution. Thank you for your answer.